# How to use 'sed' to find and replace values within a tsv file?

Tags: sed, command-line

I am currently working with a large .tsv.gz file that contains two columns that looks something like this:

```
xxxyyy  408261
yzlsdf  408260null408261
zlkajd  408258null408259null408260
asfzns  408260
```

What I'd like to do is find all the rows that contain "null" and replace it with a comma ",". So that the result would look like this:

```
xxxyyy  408261
yzlsdf  408260,408261
zlkajd  408258,408259,408260
asfzns  408260
```

I have tried using the following command but did not work:

```
sed -i 's/null/,/g' 46536657_1748327588_combined_copy.tsv.gz
```

Unzipping the file and trying it again also does not work with a tsv file.

I've also tried opening the unzipped file in a text editor to manually find and replace. But the file is too huge and would crash.

Comment: Why and how does unzipping "not work"?

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C file.tsv` to your question.

Comment: unzipping and then running the same command would give me the following error:

"sed: 1: "46536657_1748327588_com ...": invalid command code _"

Comment: @Cyrus, not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Are you trying to edit a compressed file with `sed`?

Comment: ideally yes, i'd like to do a 'find and replace' within the gz file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
zcat comb.tsv.gz | sed 's/null/,/g' | gzip >new_comb.tsv.gz && mv new_comb.tsv.gz comb.tsv.gz
```

Because this avoids unzipping your file all at once, this should save on memory.

#### Example

Let's start with this sample file:

```
$ zcat comb.tsv.gz 
xxxyyy  408261
yzlsdf  408260null408261
zlkajd  408258null408259null408260
asfzns  408260
```

Next, we run our command:

```
$ zcat comb.tsv.gz | sed 's/null/,/g' | gzip >new_comb.tsv.gz && mv new_comb.tsv.gz comb.tsv.gz
```

By looking at the output file, we can see that the substitutions were made:

```
$ zcat comb.tsv.gz 
xxxyyy  408261
yzlsdf  408260,408261
zlkajd  408258,408259,408260
asfzns  408260
```